# How do we prove that any set of N functions always contains a dominating function

Tags: functions

How do we prove or disprove the following conjecture:

Given any set of $n$ functions over positive integers:

$\{f_0(x) = y_0, f_1(x) = y_1, f_2(x) = y_2... f_{n-1}(x) = y_{n-1}\}$ such that $x_i \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and  $y_i \in \mathbb{Z^+}$.

**Conjecture:** In this set, there always exists a function such that it dominates over all other functions in the set.

**Dominating Function:** The function $f_a$ dominates over other functions in the set iff there exists at least 1 set of $n-1$ positive integers ${(x_0, x_1, x_2... x_{n-1})}$ where $(x_0\neq x_1 \neq x_2 \neq.....\neq x_{n-1})$ such that:

- $f_a(x_0) \geq f_0(x_0)$
- $f_a(x_1) \geq f_1(x_1)$
- $f_a(x_2) \geq f_2(x_2)$

I have been trying to think about induction to prove the following but I am struggling. Can someone please help?

**Edit:** $a$ represents index of some function in the set i.e. $0 \leq a < n$. Moreover, this conjecture is for **ANY** possible set of functions over positive integers.

Comment: This is not clear.  How many functions are there?  You start at $f_0$ and end at...$f_0$.  Did you mean to end at $f_n$?  Maybe $f_{n-1}$?  And the definition says nothing about any $x_i$....Did you mean to write something like $f_i(x_i)=y_i$?  Something else?

Comment: Nor is it it clear what property you want.  Perhaps it would help if you took a small example, like $n=2$, to illustrate what you had in mind.

Comment: Post edit, now you have $n+1$ functions...is that what you intended?  And should the arguments have been $x_i$?

Comment: second typo.. panic edit.. :( correcting..

Comment: I think the whole post should be rewritten for clarity.  Work out the case of some small $n$, like $n=2$, explicitly to clearly illustrate the property you are interested in.

Comment: Are these $x_i$ fixed? Is part of the question finding the right set of $x_i$ along with the right $f_a$? If so, what are $y_i$?

Comment: Nope $x_i$ are not fixed. $x_i$ is the integer input $y_i$  the output. For example: in function $x^2$ $x_i=3 => y_i=9$ We need to prove such a set of integer input values to these functions exist so that the $y_i$ is greater that the other function..

Comment: So...once again:  You really meant to write $f_i(x_i)=y_i$? Please, edit your post for clarity.

Comment: But, even that wouldn't make it clear. In that case, we'd only have information about a *single value* of each $f_i$, which wouldn't tell us anything at all about all the other values.  I think you must be omitting all the crucial assumptions here.

Comment: Ok... so in the definition of dominates, the 'domination' is only for an $n+1$-element set of integers? This looks like an intriguing question if you could elucidate it a bit :p

Comment: given two functions $f_0=x^2$ and $f_1=x^3$. The input to both is value $x=3$ the output of each is $y_0=9$ and $y_1=27$. I am struggling to see how to make it cleaer. please feel free to edit..

Comment: @Vercingetorix dominates means there is at least 1 set of $n-1$ ordered unique integer values: ${x_0, x_1, x_2.. x_{n-1}}$ such that for one function in the set namely $f_a$: $f_a(x_0) \geq f_0(x_0)$, $f_a(x_1) \geq f_1(x_1)$ and so on.. is it clearer >?

Comment: Ok... then consider the following, for all $i \leq n$, let $A_i = \{a \in \mathbb{Z}: f_i(a) \geq f_j(a) \forall j \leq n\}$. Then $\cup A_i = \mathbb{Z}$. Thus at least one $A_i$ must be infinite and choose any $n+1$ element subset of this $A_i$.

Comment: Its too compact and i am dumb enough not to understand it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've interpreted your question correctly, then this is pigeonhole-esque.

Consider $A_i = \{a \in \mathbb{Z}^+: f_i(a) \geq f_j(a) \forall j \leq n\}$ for each $i \leq n$.

Notice that $\cup_{i \leq n}A_i = \mathbb{Z}$.

This is easy to see since for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ then the set $\{f_0(a), .. , f_n(a)\}$ contains a maximum, call it $f_m(a)$ and thus $a \in A_m$.

Thus $\cup_{i \leq n}A_i = \mathbb{Z}$. As the integers are infinite at least one of these $A_i$ must be infinite. Let's say $A_a$ is infinite. So it contains at least $n+1$ elements.

Let these be $x_0, ..., x_{n} \in A$. Then by definition, $f_a(x_i) \geq f_j(x_i)$ for all $j, i \leq n$ (notice that we actually proved something stronger than asked).

Comment: in all humility i am struggling.. if possible and no too much to ask can you please dumb it down a little.. i will still take time to grasp (my background is CS)

Comment: In simple english, $A_i$ consists of the elements $a$ where $f_i(a)$ is the biggest one out of all the $f_k(a)$. Now for *any* integer $a$, there must be *some* $f_i(a)$ that is the maximum (after all, a maximum always exists). Then this $a$ would be in $A_i$ by definition. So the sets together form all the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. But the integers are infinite, and a union of finite sets can only be finite, which means that at least one of these $A_i$ must be infinite. Something that is infinite certainly has more than $n+1$ elements. Now simply check that these $n+1$ elements behave as needed.

Comment: thank you thank you and thank you. in debt :) i was approaching it wrongly.